# Limit selection choices

Tags: odoo

How do you limit selection options in a view? For instance `account.voucher` has 4 type options, but I want to display only two of them. How do you achieve that in a view definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the selection is applied on a relation field (o2m, m2m) you can play with domains on the xml view itself. If the selection is actually a selection field I'm afraid you can't do this from XML.

You should be able to do that by overriding the `fields_view_get` (or `fields_get` can't remember right now). From there you can manipulate all the stuff you want but you'll have to handle python code and XML building.

`grep "def $your_method_here" *` into addons folder is your friend ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `domain` attribute.

```
<field name="voucher_id" domain="[('type','in',['payment','receipt'])]"/>
```

This could also be done directly in the business object model:

```
_columns = {
    'voucher_id': fields.many2one('account.voucher', 'Voucher', 
                  domain="[('type','in',['payment','receipt'])]",
}
```

Comment: This is good explanation, but the field I want to limit options is not a relational field. +1